# Jinja For Loop that returns list item as a single-quoted output and a non-quoted output

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, jinja2, dbt

I have a requirement to return items from a list (using a 'for loop' in jinja) that presents the 1st item first as a single quoted value, then the same item as a non-quoted value before moving to the 2nd item in the list to repeat the same process.

For example, if I had the following list

```
items = [v1,v2,v3]
```

I would like my for loop to output the following (in this exact order)

```
desired_output = 'v1',v1,'v2',v2,'v3',v3
```

Here is my workings so far... I can only produce one output of the 'item' so I'm looking for ideas to produce both

```
items = [v1,v2,v3]

{%- for i in items %}
    '{{i}}'
    {%- if not loop.last %} , {% endif -%}    
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: `'{{ i }}' , {{ i }}` in you loop, then?

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that... It returned 'v1,v2,v3',v1,v2,v3 and this is a problem because it is out of order and also missing some single quotes

Comment: Retry it. If you are in the same loop, there is no way `i` changes in the exact same iteration.

Comment: The only possibility for this to happen is that you happen to have a string `'v1,v2,v3'` in items in the first place.

Comment: And so, you need to fix your assignation to `items` (which you are not showing here).

Comment: yes, you were correct.  Once I cleaned up the list to be a 'proper' list, it worked straight away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to confuse *strings* and *string literals*, especially when using jinja to template SQL, since you need to consider the parsing context in both languages.

A *string* is a sequence of characters *in memory* -- in other words, a *string* is data.

A *string literal* is a sequence of characters *in code* -- a *string literal* is not data until a parser reads it into memory as a *string*.

If you want a *string* with the value `v1` in memory, you would usually write that as a *string literal* `"v1"` or `'v1'` in your code, depending on the language. Jinja is basically Python, so either single or double quotes can define string literals. In most SQL dialects, only single quotes can define string literals.

If you want a *string* with the value `'v1'` in memory, you could write that as  in your code as the Python/jinja *string literal* `"'v1'"`. In this case, the outer double quotes denote the string literal, and the inner quotes become part of the string, in memory.

When you use jinja to template SQL code that contains *SQL string literals*, you need the values of the *strings* in Jinja to equal a *string literal* in SQL. These are both equivalent, and will template to the SQL string literal `'v1'`:

```sql
-- include the single quotes in the template
{% set s = "v1" %}
'{{ s }}'

-- include the single quotes in the data
{% set t = "'v1'" %}
{{ t }}
```

So with that in mind:

```sql
items = ["v1", "v2", "v3"]

{%- for i in items %}
    '{{ i }}', {{ i }}
    {%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}
{%- endfor %}
```

Will template to:

```sql
'v1', v1, 'v2', v2, 'v3', v3
```

Comment: thanks for clearing this up - I made some changes in my list after reading the above and it worked straight away